# Devise edit profile on a custom page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am really new to rails and i encountered this problem,

so I am using Devise for the authentication, the problem is I have created a separate HTML page file for user to edit their information, and I was wondering how to use it on Devise to update the users' information.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the resource and resource_name variables used by Devise, which aren't initialized from outside a "custom" Devise controller and this way use them as in every form, in any controller.

You can add them to your app/helpers/application_helper.rb to make them be available for the most of your views:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
   @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

Or in the case you don't think is needed to use the helper "way", then you can pass the resource_name in your `form_for and in your defined`url` option, like:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: session_path(:user) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```